# the sum of two unsigned 12-bit octal numbers

Tags: numbers, mips, unsigned, octal

I'm trying to understand why my calculation is giving different answer than the book.

The question ask what is the sum of A & B if they represent unsigned 12-bit octal numbers?

```
A=3174 and B=0522
```

Below is my approach to the problem:

```
1. 3174 octal = 011001111100 (unsigned 12 bits)
   0522 octal = 000101010010 (unsigned 12 bits) 
          sum = 011111001110 (unsigned 12 bits)
```

Second approach I added the two octal number straight no need converting to binary

```
3174 octal+0522 octal= 3716 octal (answer must be in octal).
```

But I don't get it how the book ended getting 7620 confused // this is in MIPS programming

Comment: I suspect you misunderstood the problem. 3174+0522 is not 7620, so you probably aren't supposed to be adding 3174 and 0522.

Comment: Can you provide some more context?

Comment: The math presented looks correct. Perhaps there is more to the question or the inputs were copied incorrectly or .. there is always a small chance a (newer) book has a few errors. Check with peers or an assistant?

Comment: Here is the full question: "The following table shows pairs of octal number: A=3174 B=0522 what is the sum of A & B if the represent unsigned 12-bit octal numbers? the result should be written in octal. show your work.

Comment: @MassiveCoding From that question, as I read it, the octal result *must* end in a 6 (and the rest of the digits agree with the posted answer) which the reported correct answer does not. Ask your peers - they've either come to the the reportedly correct answer or the same answer as you and are also scratching their heads :)

Comment: @user2864740 ME and my friend have found solutions to this questions but we are trying to compare our calculation to what is given, seems all our answers differ from the manuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [exercise 3.1.1 of *Computer Organization and Design, Revised 4<sup>th</sup> Edition*](http://books.google.com/books?id=U6lpXmu7OngC&lpg=PA283&ots=6V7kImUD-J&dq=3174%200522%20octal&pg=PA283#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Your math is correct.  [Check it with Wolfram Alpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8%5E%5E3174+%2B+8%5E%5E0522)

3174<sub>8</sub> + 0522<sub>8</sub> = 3716<sub>8</sub>

The solutions guide for the book says the answer is 7620.  (That's what I can make out through the blur over page 68 [on scribd](http://www.scribd.com/doc/126175094/Computer-Organization-and-Design-Solutions).)

Of the four numbers in the table for that exercise, there is no pair that sums to 7620<sub>8</sub> or 7620<sub>10</sub>, whether you interpret the numbers in the table as octal or decimal.  The solutions guide is either wrong, or using a very obscure interpretation of the question.

Here's the Mathematica code I used to verify:

```
inputs = {3174, 0522, 4165, 1654, 8^^3174, 8^^0522, 8^^4165, 8^^1654}
Table[{i + j, BaseForm[i + j, 8]}, {i, inputs}, {j, inputs}] // Flatten // Sort // TableForm
```

Comment: Here is the full question: "The following table shows pairs of octal number: A=3174   B=0522 what is the sum of A & B if the represent unsigned 12-bit octal numbers? the result should be written in octal. show your work.

Comment: Yes, I know that's the question.  It's [exercise 3.1.1 of *Computer Organization and Design*](http://books.google.com/books?id=U6lpXmu7OngC&lpg=PA283&ots=6V7kImUD-J&dq=3174%200522%20octal&pg=PA283#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: @robmayoff yes it is. so what your thinking on that question?

Comment: No two of the four numbers in the table sum to 7620_8 or 7620_10, whether you interpret the numbers from the table as octal or decimal.

Comment: My thinking is that the answer given in the solutions manual is wrong.  If you're doing this exercise for a class, I suggest you ask your teacher or TA to check the answer and either confirm that it's incorrect or explain how to compute it.

Comment: Thanks, it not an assignment I just wanted to better understand. I thought I wasn't seeing right so needed an external comment!

Comment: Would it be fair to say that _Computer Organization and Design_ is a really awful textbook? Every homework task we've been assigned from it has led to universal confusion and consternation, as we spend more time trying to figure out the question, than we do understanding the material. </rant>

Comment: I have no idea if it's good.  The Amazon reviews are certainly mixed.